# Any other way to design other than grid with tkinter Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Please be patient with me, I am 16 years old, only started programming about last year september on codeacademy. Anyway, I'm creating this program so I can get an end of term grade for math originally but now I have been told that the school may want to use it. Now I have to make the GUI pretty and whatnot and doing so I came across a problem, grid doesn't work with ".pack()" widgets in the same window such as my "root" so my question is:

How do I move things like a would with grid and place them where I want without such a limiting scope of "LEFT,RIGHT,BOTTOM,TOP"

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import os
from tkinter import font

from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x500")
root.configure(background="grey")
root.title("Mathematical Assistance Program")

#********Functions**********#
def About():
    Beep = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion("About", "M.A.P was created by Mykel Mills using his amazing programming skills for math  is he awesome or what?")
    if Beep == "yes":
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Thanks", "Thank you very much!")
    else:
        os.startfile("killthem.flv")
def Author():
    AuthorWindow = Toplevel()
    AuthorWindow.geometry("500x200")
    AuthorWindow.title("The Developer")
    photo = PhotoImage(file="pain.gif")
    Label1 = Label(AuthorWindow, image=photo)
    Label1.image = photo
    Label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
def AddingMatrices():
    os.startfile("MAdd.mp4")
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Here", "I've opened a PDF for you for questions.")
    os.startfile("1.pdf")
def MultiplyMatrices():
    os.startfile("MM1.mp4")
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Part 2", "Let's begin part 2!")
    os.startfile("MM2.mp4")
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Worksheet", "I'll open a worksheet for you!")
    os.startfile("MM.pdf")



#*******Menu and Sub Menu**********#
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
subMenu = Menu(menu)
CSsubMenu = Menu(menu)
MatrixSubMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Home", menu=subMenu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Choose Topic", menu=CSsubMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="About", command=About)
subMenu.add_command(label="Developer", command=Author)
subMenu.add_separator()
subMenu.add_command(label="Help", command=root.quit)
subMenu.add_command(label="Quit", command=root.quit)
MatrixSubMenu.add_command(label="Adding and Subtracting Matrices", command=AddingMatrices)
MatrixSubMenu.add_command(label="Multiplying Matrices", command=MultiplyMatrices)
CSsubMenu.add_cascade(label="Matrices", menu=MatrixSubMenu)
CSsubMenu.add_command(label="Vectors", command=root.quit)
CSsubMenu.add_command(label="Circle Theorom", command=root.quit)
CSsubMenu.add_command(label="Algebra", command=root.quit)

#*********Status Bar**********#
status = Label(root, text="Welcome to M.A.P, I will be your host today, My name is Bob, Please request for my help by clicking the help button", bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

#**********To do list******************
lf = LabelFrame(root, text="To Do", padx=5, pady=5, bg="grey")
lf.pack(side=LEFT)
label = Label(lf, text="1. Add Vector videos and questions", bg="grey")
label1 = Label(lf, text="2. Complete all other possible topics", bg="grey")
label2 = Label(lf, text="3. Create UI to be more User Friendly", bg="grey")
label3 = Label(lf, text="4. Create point system with rewards", bg="grey")
label4 = Label(lf, text="5. Design I.EM.S as soon as possible ", bg="grey")
label.pack()
label1.pack()
label2.pack()
label3.pack()
label4.pack()

#*******Home Page Title*********

label5 = Label(root, text="M.A.P", font=("Helvetica", 50), bg="grey")
label5.pack(side=TOP)









root.mainloop()
```

Thanks a million!

Comment: So use `grid()` instead of `pack()`?

Comment: What do you mean by "such a limiting scope of LEFT,RIGHT,BOTTOM,TOP"?  How do you instead want to say where to move things?

Comment: @BrenBarn LEFT,RIGHT,BOTTOM,TOP doesn't really give me many options as to where to position my things unlike .grid() which gives column and row. TigerhawkT3 but to do that I would have to rewrite all my .pack() to .grid() which I may do if .place() doesn't work well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .place()

> In absolute positioning, the programmer specifies the position and the size of each widget in pixels. The size and the position of a widget do not change if you resize a window.

.place() uses x and y coordinates to specify the placement on the window.

Example:

```
Label.place(x=40, y=50)
```

Here's the URL for a full explanation of .pack() , .grid() and .place():
http://zetcode.com/gui/tkinter/layout/

Please note:
.grid() is a much better and more organized way to make a Tkinter window. It is NOT as limited as you think, if you use the STICKY argument (Which allows you to be even more specific than just a single cell). I won't go too far into grid, since it isn't part of the question. But I would rather you use .grid() than .place()